# Virtualization on Atom D2700

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, xen, openvz

Will paravirtualization work fine on Atom D2700 with 4 Gb RAM? Just several ubuntu/debian (maybe others) VM's with not heavy loads (LAMP for tests, torrent client, file server for PC and Mac etc.). And what will be faster XEN or OpenVZ?

P.S. Host - Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

Paravirtualization does not require VT-d or VT-x like full virtualization. Because of this, it should be do-able, but be warned that performance will be dismal.

[That CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/59683/Intel-Atom-Processor-D2700-1M-Cache-2_13-GHz) only has 1 MB of L2 cache, no L3 cache, 2 cores, and a max of 4GB RAM.

Comment: +1 For Xen: PV requires supporting Guest OSes (Linux, NetBSD, FreeBSD and OpenSolaris only as of writing). HVM requires VT/AMD-V. There are PVHVM drivers so that HVM guests can run like PV guests (faster/slower/same speed will depend on a variety of specics.

Comment: i'm running xen pv on atom. there will be problem when writing file to disk. cpu usage run at 100% when writing and going back to normal after finishing writing process.